# Xcode Ambiguous reference to member 'init'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I used the code below in the Xcode 10 beta 3 and it worked. When I then moved it to Xcode 9 to upload to the iTunes Connect I got the error below. Below is also the code. Why would it work in the beta but not in 9?

Ambiguous reference to member 'init'
1. Overloads for 'init' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (Wrapped), (nilLiteral: ())

[image: error]

```
 @objc func handleLongPressBuss(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {


    guard let index = ChannelText.index(where: { $0 == sender.view }) else { assertionFailure(); return }

    let buslist = "\(sharedData.ChannelBuss[index])"
    let M = "M"
    let A = "A"
    let B = "B"

    let busViewController = BusViewController.instantiate()
    busViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    busViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = ChannelText[index]

    busViewController.state = .init(
        isMOn: buslist.contains(M),
        isAOn: buslist.contains(A),
        isBOn: buslist.contains(B),
        index: index,
        channelTitle: ("\(sharedData.ChannelLabel[index])")
    )

    present(busViewController, animated: true)

}
```

here is the buscontroller

```
import UIKit

final class BusViewController: UIViewController {

func makeBusRequestOn(bus: String, inputNumber: Int) -> NSMutableURLRequest
{
    print()
    return NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "\(baserequest)AudioBusOn&Value=\(bus)&Input=\(inputNumber)" )!)

}
func makeBusRequestOff(bus: String, inputNumber: Int) -> NSMutableURLRequest
{
    print()
    return NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "\(baserequest)AudioBusOff&Value=\(bus)&Input=\(inputNumber)" )!)

}

struct State {
    var isMOn: Bool
    var isAOn: Bool
    var isBOn: Bool
    var index: Int
    var channelTitle: String

}
var state: State!


static func instantiate() -> BusViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BusViewController") as! BusViewController
}
@IBAction func masterChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {

    print(sender.isOn)
    let requestURL: NSMutableURLRequest
    if sender.isOn {
        requestURL = makeBusRequestOn(bus: "M", inputNumber: state.index + 1 )
    }
    else {
        requestURL = makeBusRequestOff(bus: "M", inputNumber: state.index + 1 )
    }

    httpGet2(requestURL as URLRequest?) { string, error in
        guard error == nil && string != nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? 777)
            return
        }
        print(string!)
    }
}

@IBAction func busAChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    print(sender.isOn)
    let requestURL: NSMutableURLRequest
    if sender.isOn {
        requestURL = makeBusRequestOn(bus: "A", inputNumber: state.index + 1 )
    }
    else {
        requestURL = makeBusRequestOff(bus: "A", inputNumber: state.index + 1 )
    }

    httpGet2(requestURL as URLRequest?) { string, error in
        guard error == nil && string != nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? 777)
            return
        }
        print(string!)
    }
}
@IBAction func busBChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    print(sender.isOn)
    let requestURL: NSMutableURLRequest
    if sender.isOn {
        requestURL = makeBusRequestOn(bus: "B", inputNumber: state.index + 1 )
    }
    else {
        requestURL = makeBusRequestOff(bus: "B", inputNumber: state.index + 1 )
    }

    httpGet2(requestURL as URLRequest?) { string, error in
        guard error == nil && string != nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? 777)
            return
        }
        print(string!)
    }
}
@IBOutlet var channelLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var masterLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var masterSwitch: UISwitch!

@IBOutlet var busALabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var busASwitch: UISwitch!

@IBOutlet var busBLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var busBSwitch: UISwitch!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    updateUI()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let size = view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
    preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: size.width + 30, height: size.height)


}

func updateUI() {
    masterSwitch.isOn = state.isMOn
    busASwitch.isOn = state.isAOn
    busBSwitch.isOn = state.isBOn
    channelLabel.text = state.channelTitle
}


@IBAction func okTapped() {
    dismiss(animated: true)

}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the busViewController class?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can't use the short hand `.init(...)`, because the type of `state` is `State!`, aka `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<State>`. `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` doesn't have the `State` initializer you want to use.

A simple example can be used to demonstrate this:

```
var s: String = .init() // OK
var s: String! = .init() // Fails
```

But you can't simply remove the optional type because then your controller needs an initializer to initialise `state`. So I think the best way to solve this is to just write it the type name: `State(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with a simplified code in Xcode 9.4.1, this compiles.

```
class BusViewController {
    var state: State? //<- Not "Implicitly Unwrapped"
    //...
}

let busViewController = BusViewController()

busViewController.state = .init(
    isMOn: true,
    isAOn: true,
    isBOn: true,
    index: 0,
    channelTitle: ""
)
```

Seems type inference for dot-leaded notation works smart enough for (usual) `Optional` even in Xcode 9.

One reason your code compiles in Xcode 10 beta, would be related to this:

[Reimplementation of Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals](https://swift.org/blog/iuo/)

Whole re-implementation of Implicitly Unwrapped Optional has finished in Xcode 10, so the behavior for implicitly unwrapped Optional has become the same as (usual) `Optional`.

---

But I do not recommend you to use implicitly unwrapped Optional `State!` for `state`, as it may be accessed before non-nil value given. You should better declare it as usual Optional `State?` and rewrite your code as Optional-safe way where you access `state`.

One more, better use `URLRequest` than `NSMutableURLRequest` in Swift.

Comment: Let me try this thank you. The problem is that changing "isMOn" will cause my switches to not reflect that data I am bringing in as well as remove the title of my input.